# Weird behaviour of the AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi fellow android developers.

I am having a weird issue with the setMultiChoiceItems method of the AlertDialog.Build class. When I pass an array of CharSequence and an array of boolean (with all item set to true) to the method the resulting dialog shows all items selected except for items on positions 11 (10 zero based), 22 (21 zero based) ... which means that it somehow ignores the check state indicated by the array of booleans after each 10 items!

Here is the sample code:

```
CharSequence[] items = {
            "Item01", "Item02", "Item03", "Item04", "Item05",
            "Item06", "Item07", "Item08", "Item09", "Item10",
            "Item11", "Item12", "Item13", "Item14", "Item15",
            "Item16", "Item17", "Item18", "Item19", "Item20",
            "Item21", "Item22", "Item23", "Item24", "Item25",
            "Item26", "Item27", "Item28", "Item29", "Item30"};
    boolean[] flags = {
            true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true};
    DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b)
        {

        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Set the dialog title
    dialog.setTitle("Title")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(
                    items,
                    flags,
                    listener)
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(
                    "Apply",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(
                    "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
    dialog.show();
```

And here are tow screenshots of the app:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Your code is fine, are you 100% sure nothing else in your code can change what items are checked before the dialog is displayed?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure, I had this issue in  a bigger project, then to make sure nothing is interfering with the code I created a new project with one activity and I called this code in the OnCreate mehod of the main activity. So this is the only code I have in the new app now.

Comment: What is more weird is that if I turn off the phone screen and turn it on again (which suggest that onResume is called) I find that the unchecked items are checked!

Comment: Furthermore, if I click on the items that are initially unchecked they remain unchecked unless I click on them a second time ! which suggests that they are correctly checked but they are displayed as unchecked somehow

Comment: This is really weird, does it happen on other devices? You may try to change the version of the support library you are using, maybe it has a bug (and ensure that you are using the AlertDialog from the support library).

Comment: I gave up on the setMultiChoiceItems, I implement my own dialog using the setView method and a ListView with multichoice mode.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question by the way :)